# Get all associated records after filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm hitting a wall with the filters.

I have two models and the relative rails_admin conf:

```rb
class ImageBase < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors, optional: true
  [...]
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :image_bases, class_name: 'ImageBase'
  [...]
end

config.model 'ImageBase' do
    list do
      scopes [:published, :draft, nil]
      filters %i[collocazione authors]
      [...]
      field :authors do # (4)
        eager_load true
        queryable true
        visible true
        searchable %i[name surname]
      end
      search_by :search_image_base_admin
    end
end
```

My problem is that when I filter the ImageBase by Author in Rails_admin the results only show the matching Author and not all the authors related to the imagebase record.

I need this mainly to export the data after the filtering, it is not just an issue in the listing view (I can live with that)

Can't find a solution in the docs nor on the net,
any suggestion/solution?

Thanks
Francesco

Comment: I don't understand your question, when you say "to the imagebase record" what record do you mean? you are configuring the list of image base records so if you filter by a single actor you'll get only image base record related to that specific actor. Could you reformulate your question?

Comment: What I mean is: when I filter ImageBase (my main table) by Author (relation m2m) in rails_admin the results show me only the same Author i filtered by in the ImageBase results, not all the Authors related to the records.
Example:
ImageBaseRecord1 <id:23,Authors:[Picasso,Bresson]>, when I filter by "Picasso" i get in ImageBaseRecord1 only "Picasso"

Comment: If you are on the ImageBase list view of rails admin and you search for records that are associated with Picasso(through the authors m2m) you would get that, why would you expect to also get records associated with Bresson also? Sorry i still don't understand your expectation.

Comment: because if an ImageBase record have two Authors associated I need to see both and not only the one I filtered for... otherwise I get incorrect data when I export the results!

Comment: Sorry i can't help you it does not make sense to me what you are asking.

Comment: don't worry, this happens when you work on a pretty complex project. I will rewrite the query builder of rails_admin. But honestly can't see why you can't see the need to have the complete data, truncated it's just misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood but you can always override the built in search and build your own with a scope, like this

```
  RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.model ImageBase do
      list do
        search_by :custom_search
      end
    end
  end

scope :custom_search, ->(query) { where(name: query.reverse) }
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is in the filter section, not in the search per se.
Filters are processed before the scope by rails_admin.

Comment: You can always do unscope.where(something) but you'd lose pagination too